# Displaying time selected from TimePicker to display Local Notification in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show Local Notification at the time that I have selected using TimePicker. I can call the function of scheduleAlaram() but I cannot send the time that i selected. Please help me out with how do I send this time to my function in order to display local notification.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:epicare/Medicines.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_switch/flutter_switch.dart';

class AddMedicine extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddMedicineState createState() => _AddMedicineState();
}

class _AddMedicineState extends State<AddMedicine> {
  final timeController = TextEditingController();

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String value = "";
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(),

body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
Container(
              width: size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 34, vertical: 13),
              child: Text(
                'Reminder',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: size.width * 0.85,
              height: 52,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: const Color(0xffdbe2ea)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: const Color(0x0a2c2738),
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                    blurRadius: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: timeController,
                readOnly: true,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var time = await showTimePicker(
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                          return Theme(
                            data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                                primary: const Color(0xffE5E0A1),
                                onPrimary: Colors.black,
                                surface: Colors.white,
                                onSurface: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              dialogBackgroundColor:Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: child,
                          );
                        },
                          context: context,
                          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                          
                      );
                      print(time.format(context));
                      timeController.text = time.format(context);
                      scheduleAlarm();

                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add_alert,
                      color: const Color(0xffd4d411),
                    ),
                  ),
                  contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 20),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Add time(s) to eat your medicine",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: const Color(0xffcbd0d6),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  value = text;
                  print(value);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
void scheduleAlarm() async {
    //print("hello");
    var time = Time(2, 37, 0);
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails('repeatDailyAtTime channel id',
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel name', 'repeatDailyAtTime description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
        0,
        'show daily title',
        'Daily notification shown at approximately ${(time.hour)}:${(time.minute)}}',
        time,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
}
```

This is the screen which I am currently working on and I am on Reminder section to display notification:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I send this time to my function in order to display local notification.

Update `showAlarm()` to accept an argument for the time like so:

```
void scheduleAlarm(Time time) {
...
}
```

Since `showDailyAtTime()` accepts a value of `Time`, you should call the updated function after converting the value from the textcontroller to a `Time` value,

`Time.format(context)` will return a String so it cannot be used,

However you can modify this line `var time = Time(2, 37, 0);` to create a time value from the inputvalue and convert it to time using `Time()`  which can then be sent to the `scheduleAlarm()` function

Comment: What argument do I have to send in scheduleAlarm( ) where I have written my time.format(context);

Comment: Do i have to write scheduleAlarm(time.format(context)); in calling function ?

Comment: When converting text editing controller to Time its giving me this error error: A value of type 'TextEditingController' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Time'.

Comment: Could you share the code of  how you are doing that?

Comment: I am writing this line by changing final to Time in "Time timeController = TextEditingController();"

Comment: You will not be able to get a time value from a TextEditingController(), To convert the user-input into a Time value you will need to convert timeController.value to Time, this wont directly work you will need to extract the Hours, Minutes and Seconds from your string.

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that

Comment: Do consider marking this as the accepted answer, so we can help others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231549/discussion-between-nabia-salman-and-rohan-thacker).